# Is vs are for a plural sentence

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences is correct/better? And why?

- A group of soldiers **is** called a regiment
- A group of soldiers **are** called a regiment

Please support your answer with a similar example sentence.

Comment: Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74019/a-group-of-boys-is-are) answer your question? Also [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/658/the-group-of-fifty-people-is-are-going-to-arrive-thursday-which-is-prefe)

Comment: In this case, the complement contains the singular noun "regiment", so it would be better to use the singular verb "is".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A group of boys is/are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74019/a-group-of-boys-is-are)

Answer (score 0):

When you determine if a word is plural or singular you look at the form of the word so to say instead of the definition.
Here we have one group of soldiers, soldiers is plural, but we are refering to the complete noun of "a group of soldiers". This is only one group so it is singular and we use is.

Another sentence could be:

> Our soccer team has outdone themselves this year.

A soccer team consists of multiple people, but we are talking about one team, so we use the singular has.